# batch file (windows cmd.exe) test if a file is a link

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, symlink

How can I test if a file is a symbolic link from a batch file (windows cmd.exe)?

(I would have thought that this was a well phrased question, but stackoverflow appears to want me to write some more, so here it is!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    dir %filename% | find "<SYMLINK>" && (
      Do something
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful and concise.   How do I rephrase it so that I can use it in an if statement, as the condition?  if %filename% is symlink do (stuff)    kind of thing?

Comment: almost the same .Check my edit.Check this for more info http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php

Comment: Thanks.   Now I realise that my question was about directories :)   I accepted this answer and asked a new question about directories ...

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=2delims=[]" %%a in ('dir /ad ^|find "<SYMLINKD>"') do echo Symlink: "%%a"
```

This doesn't work with `[]` in Symlink names.

Comment: Thanks!  I am learning a lot from this.  Can you help me rephrase this so that I can say if %FILE% is a symlink do (stuff) ?

Comment: +1 This probably doesn’t answer the original question but helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an even faster solution as it doesn't require a pipe and also allows access to the original file name either as a relative or absolute path:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set ScriptPath=%~dp0
cd /d "%ScriptPath%"

set "r=%__CD__%"

set SearchTarget=SomePath

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:l %SearchTarget% 2^>nul') do (
   set "FullPath=%%a"
   set "LocalPath=!:%r%=!"

   rem local -> [absolute]
   echo(!FullPath:%r%=! -^> [%%a]
)
```

If you don't want to search recursively then remove the `/s` option for the `dir` command.